# Error message: ´)´expected, and "not a statement" ´;´expected

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I´m totally new to programming in java, and following some basic tutorials for my self.
I´m trying to solve an excercise wich tells me to make a small program where the user types in an amonunt of seconds. The program is then supposed to return how many hours, minutes and seconds this is. I can´t get ridd of the error messages. Can anyone help me please?
My code is the following

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Time2
{
   public static void main( String args[] )
   {
      // Defining types of data:
      String secondstring;
      int minutes;
      int seconds;
      int hours;
      int seconds1;
      int seconds2;

      // Making inputwindow and initializing the variable sekondstring:
      secondstring = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Type in seconds!" );

      // Converting secondstring to type int:
      seconds = Integer.parseInt( secondstring );

      // Initializing the variables seconds, minutes and hour:
      hours = seconds / 3600;
      seconds1 = seconds % 3600;
      minutes = seconds1 / 60;
      seconds2 = seconds1 % 60;

      // Making output box:
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "That will be " + hours "hours, " + minutes "minutes, and " + seconds2 "seconds.", "Result", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE );

    } // End of main method.
} // End of class Time2
```

I get the following error-message when I try to compile:

```
Time2.java:28: ')' expected
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "That will be " + hours "hours, " + minutes "minutes, and " + seconds2 "seconds.", "Result", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE );
                                                                ^
Time2.java:28: not a statement
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "That will be " + hours "hours, " + minutes "minutes, and " + seconds2 "seconds.", "Result", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE );
                                                                           ^
Time2.java:28: ';' expected
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "That will be " + hours "hours, " + minutes "minutes, and " + seconds2 "seconds.", "Result", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE );
                                                                                    ^
Time2.java:28: not a statement
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "That will be " + hours "hours, " + minutes "minutes, and " + seconds2 "seconds.", "Result", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE );
                                                                                                       ^
Time2.java:28: ';' expected
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "That will be " + hours "hours, " + minutes "minutes, and " + seconds2 "seconds.", "Result", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE );
                                                                                                               ^
Time2.java:28: not a statement
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "That will be " + hours "hours, " + minutes "minutes, and " + seconds2 "seconds.", "Result", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE );
                                                                                                                                                 ^
Time2.java:28: ';' expected
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "That will be " + hours "hours, " + minutes "minutes, and " + seconds2 "seconds.", "Result", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE );
                                                                                                                                                               ^
7 errors
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After each of `hours`, `minutes` and `seconds2` you need to add a `+` sign before the double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

should be this:

```
"That will be " + hours + "hours, " + minutes  + "minutes, and " + seconds2 + "seconds."
```

Answer (score 1):

The error-message is a little bit tricky. The real problem is here:

seconds2 "seconds."
(there is a missing "+" sign between the two variables)